# ng-repeat not populating table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've populated a table with data from a JSON file, and then when the user clicks on an item in the table, a container and it's fields display below and it SHOULD be populated with that specific data, though it isn't.

The function `select` is invoked through `list-patents.htm` which contains the table with a list of patents. I have used the `$rootScope` object so the function is accessible from multiple controllers i.e. `patentDetailsCtrl`

Why isn't my table in `patent-item.htm` being populated with the `ng-repeat` directive?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment', 'ui.router', "chart.js"]);

$stateProvider   
    .state("patents.list.item", {
        url: "/patent-item",
        templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm",
        params: {
            id: null,
            appNo: null,
            clientRef: null,
            costToRenew: null,
            renewalDueDate: null,
            basketStatus: null,
            costBandEnd: null,
            nextStage: null
        },
        controller: "patentDetailsCtrl"
    })

app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.select = function() {       
        return $rootScope.patentItem = item;
    }
});

app.controller('patentDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.selectedPatent = $scope.patentItem;

    console.log($scope.selectedPatent);


}]);
```

---

**list-patents.htm**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in patents">
        <td ng-click="select(x)"><a ui-sref="patents.list.item({id: x.id, appNo: x.applicationNumber, clientRef: x.clientRef, costToRenew: x.costToRenew, renewalDueDate: x.renewalDueDate, basketStatus: x.basketStatus, costBandEnd: x.costBandEnd, nextStage: x.nextStage})">{{x.applicationNumber}}</a></td>
        <td ng-bind="x.clientRef"></td>
        <td ng-bind="x.costToRenew">$</td>
        <td ng-bind="x.renewalDueDate"></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(x.id)">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**patent-item.htm**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>applicationNumber</td>
                <td>clientRef</td>
                <td>costToRenew</td>
                <td>renewalDueDate</td>
                <td>basketStatus</td>
                <td>costBandEnd</td>
                <td>nextStage</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in selectedPatent">
                <td>{{x.applicationNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{x.clientRef}}</td>
                <td>{{x.costToRenew}}</td>
                <td>{{x.renewalDueDate}}</td>
                <td>{{x.basketStatus}}</td>
                <td>{{x.costBandEnd}}</td>
                <td>{{x.nextStage}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: typo mistakes in the code. Missing paranthesis at `$rootScope.select`. first make sure that there are no syntax errors

Comment: Apologies, was removing a `console.log`

Comment: what is `item`, in `return $rootScope.patentItem = item;` line ?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: could you please create a fiddle?

Comment: @anoop It is a value passed from `list-patents.htm` where the function is invoked. It's how I select the specific item from the JSON file to be displayed

Comment: @AhammadaliPK  I'll have a go but it involves a couple of views, controllers and services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct below points:

1. your `$rootScope.select()` method doesn't accept data (`select(x)`) passed from your `list-patents.htm`, So put `item` as param.,
   Like : `$rootScope.select = function(item) {  \\ code`
2. Sine you do `ng-repeat` on `$rootScope.patentItem`, then I guess you need to make it `array`, and `push the passed data to it`. (No need of return statement as well.)

So run block should be like  :

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
 rootScope.patentItem = [];
 $rootScope.select = function(item) {       
    $rootScope.patentItem.push(item);
 }
});
```

See this [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gm93yefh/)

Comment: When you say $rootScope.select() method doesn't accept data, how can that be? The selected object is showing in my console. I just need to work out how to populate the subsequent table with only that information

Comment: when you do `ng-click="select(x)"`, where is `x` going ?, I hope it will be taken by rotscope method ,like `$rootScope.select = function(item) {  `, which you further assign to `$rootScope.patentItem`., rather you should  `push` it.. hope it clarify. ..:)

Comment: It is taken by the $rootScope.select function. I think I misunderstood what you meant. I thought you were saying it doesn't accept arguments from the view

Comment: But it does, it display all details I want in the console. Now all I want to do is populate second table with `ng-repeat` but it's not display the data

Comment: see updated answer., and please ensure you get data in console after `console.log($scope.selectedPatent);` in controller ?

Comment: Appreciate the effort, I think the issue is lying within `ng-repeat`. The table rows are displayed, but no content as the data isn't being found. I have the specified object selected, and based on my code, I need to populate the table with `ng-repeat`

Comment: I'm not sure if you get my answer, but I'm pretty sure your `selectedPatent` array doesn't have data to iterate, because you didn't provide data to it. Could you verify ` console.log($scope.selectedPatent);` , actually logs data. ? because in controller you get data from rootscope, `$scope.selectedPatent = $scope.patentItem;`

Comment: Well the table below is populating which is good progress so thank you for that! Only issue is, data is added to the table, rather than replacing the current data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146054/discussion-between-anoop-and-patrick-mcdermott).

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you're trying to access the patentItem selected in your select function. If you're passing it to the $rootScope this way, you will also need to access it this way.

So change the line as follows...

```
$scope.selectedPatent = $rootScope.patentItem
```

Comment: The function is declared in the `$rootScope`, so as I understand, I can access it with just `$scope` from any of my controllers

Comment: no you can't, the function in the root scope must be accessed by $rootScope from any controller not just $scope, but you still can access it from any view (html) normally